# how to implement a login script using PHP

Tags: php

I've found this login script and I'm trying to implement it into my website but having a little trouble:

```
// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testing") or die(mysql_error());

//checks cookies to make sure they are logged in
if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
{
    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'];
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or      die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
    {
        //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page
        if ($pass != $info['password'])
        {
            header("Location: loginscript.php");
        }

        //otherwise they are shown the admin area
        else
        {
            echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
        }
    }
}
else
    //if the cookie does not exist, they are taken to the login screen
{
    header("Location: newlogin.php");
}
```

I want to get rid of:

```
        else 

        { 

     echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>"; 

        }
```

as it messes with my css, I just want the last part of the else statement to work but when i take it out it errors out.

how do I do this??

thanks

Comment: Seems that you're removing the end block of the statement.

Comment: What is the modified version of the code and what is the error?  Hint: Fixing the indentation of your code may help identify syntax errors like mis-matched brackets.

Comment: @david this is the modified code: http://pastebin.com/8ahSMR3R and the error message is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in E:\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\test.php on line 207 which is just a HTML tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("testing") or die(mysql_error()); 


//checks cookies to make sure they are logged in 

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])) 

 { 

    $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site']; 

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or      die(mysql_error()); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))   
    { 


         //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page 

            if ($pass != $info['password']) 

            {
                   header("Location: loginscript.php"); 
                } 



                 //otherwise they are shown the admin area  


        } 

    } 

    else 

{

//if the cookie does not exist, they are taken to the login screen 


    header("Location: newlogin.php"); 

}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the section you highlighted just fine.

```
else 
{ 
echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>"; 
}
```

if that doesn't work then you can try to remove the echo text.

```
else 
{ 
echo ""; 
}
```

Comment: i think i was trying to remove the parenthsis's too this works as well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot contest to the effectiveness of this as a auth/login script but this should run fine:

```
<?php
    // Connects to your Database 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("testing") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //checks cookies to make sure they are logged in
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
    { 
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site']; 

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or      die(mysql_error()); 

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
        {
            //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page 
            if ($pass != $info['password']) 
            {
                header("Location: loginscript.php"); 
            }
            //else //otherwise they are shown the admin area 
            //{ 
            //  echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>"; 
            //} 
        }
    }
    else //if the cookie does not exist, they are taken to the login screen 
    {
        header("Location: newlogin.php");
    } 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of re-formatting the code from the [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/8ahSMR3R) you posted in a comment:

```
<?php 
    // Connects to your Database 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("testing") or die(mysql_error()); 
    //checks cookies to make sure they are logged in 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])) 
    {
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site']; 
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error()); 
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))   
        { 
            //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page 
            if ($pass != $info['password']) 
            {
                header("Location: loginscript.php"); 
            } 
            //otherwise they are shown the admin area    
            else 
            //if the cookie does not exist, they are taken to the login screen 
            {            
                header("Location: newlogin.php"); 
            } 
?>
```

As you can see, you never close your curly braces for the `while` loop or the top-level `if` statement.  Hence, your error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in E:\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\test.php on line 207

One hint I can give you is that when a syntax error references a point in the code, look immediately *before* that point for the actual problem.  The point that the parser got to which produced the error is the unexpected part, which means something just before it is broken.

And, of course, always properly format your code for spacing and indentation.  It makes these things *much* easier to track down and correct.

Comment: thanks thats very helpful. I'm trying to learn but it is all very new to me!